# DAX Countrows with operators

Tags: powerbi, dax

Have I done this correctly if I want to count rows based on these conditions:

```
First time fix = CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(SLA), SLA[Antall svar]=1 || SLA[Antall svar]=2 && SLA[Status]="Avsluttet" && SLA[Avdeling] = "Kunde- og kompetansetjenester", USERELATIONSHIP(DIM_DATO[Opprettet], SLA[Opprettet]))
```

I tried to validate the number in a matrix and the measure is apparently returning the wrong number:

[image]

However, if I create two measures and add them together it will return the correct number.

```
First time fix (1) = CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(SLA), SLA[Antall svar]=1 && SLA[Status]="Avsluttet" && SLA[Avdeling] = "Kunde- og kompetansetjenester", USERELATIONSHIP(DIM_DATO[Opprettet], SLA[Opprettet]))

First time fix (2) = CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(SLA), SLA[Antall svar]=2 && SLA[Status]="Avsluttet" && SLA[Avdeling] = "Kunde- og kompetansetjenester", USERELATIONSHIP(DIM_DATO[Opprettet], SLA[Opprettet]))

First time fix = [First time fix (1)]+[First time fix (2)]
```

[image]